# finding solutions numerically of the equation

Tags: equation-solving

given the equation x^5 - y^5 = 1 ,x-2y=1 i need to find the numerical values of the solutions. Now as far as i know N is the command that we'll be using to get numerical values , NSolve for solving the equation numerically and that it must contain in the output, numbers , not symbols, but i havent been specified either to solve for x or y, nor have i been given values for any of them . if i choose to solve for x , the output gives solution containing y and solving for y gives result in x, these arent numerical forms of solutions. the N command is only used to give a value numerically. how can i get that in this equation? or maybe i can use another command that can be helpful?

Comment: "whats with the double slash ?" If you see a function or an operator that you don't understand, highlight it and press `F1` for help.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
sol=NSolve[{x^5 + y^5 == 1, x - 2 y == 1}, {x, y}]
(*{{x -> -0.719188 - 0.694816 I,y -> -0.859594 - 0.347408 I}    
, {x -> -0.719188 + 0.694816 I,y -> -0.859594 + 0.347408 I}
, {x -> 0.294945 - 0.955514 I,y -> -0.352527 - 0.477757 I}
, {x -> 0.294945 + 0.955514 I,y -> -0.352527 + 0.477757 I}
, {x -> 1., y -> 0.}}*)
```

which evaluates all 5 solutions!

Comment: if i were to find the absolute values of the solutions , how do i proceed?

Comment: `{Abs[x], Abs [y]} /. sol`

Comment: Or, since `Abs` is `Listable`: `Abs[{x, y}] /. sol`